# Adjective or Adverb?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, adjectives

In my math textbook, I saw an author use “square and invertible matrix.” Which one is more correct: “invertible square matrix” or “invertibly square matrix”?

Comment: Ask a mathematician. Specialized language like that is decided by the people who use it regularly, not by grammarians or linguists.

Comment: Invertible square matrix. It's a square matrix that's invertible, not a matrix that's 'square in an invertible way' (which would make no sense). As John L well knows. Though his 'comment' is really the more appropriate.

Comment: If you solve a square matrix problem involving inversion, you will know which phrase to use. So I'd suggest that you go solve a matrix problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [math.se] with the terminology tag.

Comment: My LA is a little rusty, but Nicholas' answer is correct. Also, @CJDennis, I disagree with closing; while this does deal with a math term, I think understanding *why* "invertible" is correct and "invertibly" is not is on topic. BTW, also, "invertible square" is redundant; only square matrices can be invertible.

Comment: @Matthew That's fine. It take five users to close a question. If other users vote to leave it open, it won't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

With my limited knowledge on Linear Algebra, I view it as such:

***invertible square matrix***

This means your matrix is both square and invertible. It has an order of n*m where n equals m, and it is also invertible.

***invertibly square matrix***

This implies that your matrix is square, and how square is it? It is *invertibly* square. I do not know if that even makes sense to say that something is invertibly square. Something can be *almost* square or *perfectly* square or *permanently* square, but I don't see how *invertibly* square could possibly mean anything.

Thus, I would say that using an adjective here probably means what you intended to mean.